# How do I select a second radio button group automatically by selecting the first group?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's my Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/vuzqRCcxGsKTgRbEEhJV?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module("myApp");
        app.controller("appCTRL",function($scope,$http){
            $scope.thing = {
              food: '',
              color: ''
            };
        });     
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCTRL">
  <form>
    <input type="radio" value="carrot" ng-model="thing.food" name="food">Carrot
    <input type="radio" value="apple" ng-model="thing.food" name="food">Apple
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="orange" ng-model="thing.color" name="color">Orange
    <input type="radio" value="red" ng-model="thing.color" name="color">Red
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I select the "carrot" radio button, I'd like for "orange" to be selected automatically. If I select "apple," I'd like "red" to get selected;

How do I do this with AngularJS?

Comment: @Claies I'd like for there to be no possibility of a `red` `carrot`. I used singular because I'm unfamiliar with AngularJS naming conventions.

Comment: @Claies I think this should work.

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing this. Look into [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)ing your $scope properties or just get really simple and add [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)s to your radio buttons. Honestly, you should take [the tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06) and learn some of the basics of data binding.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I agree that there are many ways to accomplish this.  I chose to show how this can be done with just basic angular bindings because I feel like people make these radios way more complicated than they need to be, with `$watch` in particular.

Comment: @Claies sure, but in general I think it's best to get a grounding in the basics of the framework first. Find out what you can do, what you shouldn't do, etc.. Your answer is great, but could have perhaps waited for a better question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sure, and that's why at first I was trying to prod Username to improve the code.  In the end, I still felt like this was a pretty representative example, and simplistic enough to implement without too much angular experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your plunker and created a new example, with a couple different ways to accomplish this.  In both examples, I defined an array of `fruits` which can hold the different possible combinations.

```
$scope.fruits = [{
    food: 'carrot',
    color: 'orange'
}, {
    food: 'apple',
    color: 'red'
}];
```

In the first example, I statically assigned the checkboxes to the objects, like so:

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="fruits[0]" ng-model="thing">{{fruits[0].food}}
<input type="radio" ng-value="fruits[1]" ng-model="thing">{{fruits[1].food}}
<br>
<input type="radio" ng-value="fruits[0]" ng-model="thing">{{fruits[0].color}}
<input type="radio" ng-value="fruits[1]" ng-model="thing">{{fruits[1].color}}
<br> {{thing}}
```

Here, all the input boxes are bound to the `thing` object, and their value is determined by which `fruits` array element they correspond to.

In the second example, I used `ng-repeat` to dynamically generate the inputs, which makes for a much more flexible configuration:

```
<label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
<input type="radio" ng-value="fruit" ng-model="selected.fruit">{{fruit.food}}</label>
<br>
<label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
<input type="radio" ng-value="fruit" ng-model="selected.fruit">{{fruit.color}}</label>
<br> {{selected}}
```

When using `ng-repeat`, any number of radio buttons could be dynamically generated by adding objects to the `fruits` array.

Note, I could also have iterated through the `fruits` array once in a `<div>` and generated both the `fruit` and `color` radios, but for this example, I chose to keep the same layout.

Also of note, when using `ng-repeat`, a child scope is created, so an object property is required for `ng-model`. Binding to `thing` or `selected` directly won't work.  (`$parent.thing` would work, but I try to steer clear of `$parent`.)

Full Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myModule", []);
    app.controller("appCTRL", function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.thing = {};

      $scope.selected = {
        fruit: {}
      };

      $scope.fruits = [{
        food: 'carrot',
        color: 'orange'
      }, {
        food: 'apple',
        color: 'red'
      }];
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="appCTRL">
  <input type="radio" ng-value="fruits[0]" ng-model="thing">{{fruits[0].food}}
  <input type="radio" ng-value="fruits[1]" ng-model="thing">{{fruits[1].food}}
  <br>
  <input type="radio" ng-value="fruits[0]" ng-model="thing">{{fruits[0].color}}
  <input type="radio" ng-value="fruits[1]" ng-model="thing">{{fruits[1].color}}
  <br> {{thing}}

  <h2>Using ng-repeat</h2>
  <label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <input type="radio" ng-value="fruit" ng-model="selected.fruit">{{fruit.food}}</label>
  <br>
  <label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <input type="radio" ng-value="fruit" ng-model="selected.fruit">{{fruit.color}}</label>
  <br> {{selected}}
</body>

</html>
```

Forked Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/VY16Lb6L5xJvdt7ROY7O?p=preview